# SELECT in Criteria Queries

Tags: select, jpa, criteria, multi-select

I have this class for example:

```
public class Person {
    private Integer id;  
    private String name;  
    private Address address;  
}

public class Address {
    private Integer id;  
    private String street;  
    private String number;      

    ...
}
```

I would like a build CriteriaQuery in JPA for this SQL

```
select p.name, d.street from Person p join Address d on d = p.address;
```

Do I have to create a Constructor for class `Person` and class `Address` for this particular situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` condition is invalid:

```
select p.name, d.street from Person p join Address d on d = p.address;
```

it should be something like:

```
select p.name, d.street from Person p join Address d on d.person_id = p.id;
```

or:

```
select p.name, d.street from Person p join Address d on d.id = p.address_id;
```

and an example for constructors for class Person:

```
//cTor I
public Person(Integer id, String name, Address address){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}

//cTor II
public Person(Integer id, String name, Integer addressId, String street, String number){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = new Address(addressId, street, number);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Now how can I make a Criteria with this JPQL?

Answer (score 0):

from JPQL 
`select p.name, d.street from Person p join Address d on d = p.address;` 
TO Criteria

an option with constructor:

first mark the relation in your entity
@OneToOne/@OneToMany or etc..
use @JoinColumn 
i.e

```
    public class Person {
           private Integer id;  
           private String name;  

           @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id")
           private Address address;  
}
```

later 
create a class for your result type

```
      public class Result(){
           String name;
            String street;

         /* you must have constructor here for the multi select later */
         public Result(String name,String street) {
            this.name = name;
            thi.street = street
         }
      }
```

then do (em is the entity manager)

```
      CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
      CriteriaQuery<PlaceSearch> query = cb.createQuery(PlaceSearch.class);
  Root<Person> personRoot = query.from(Person .class);
  Join<Person, Address> address= personRoot .join(Person_.address);

      / * without meta model 
  Join<Person, Address> address= personRoot .join(person.get("address"));
      */
/* we know Result has a construct of (String,String) . this is important for the                        multi select here */

query.multiselect(person.get(Person_.name),address.get(Address_.street);
List<Result> result = em.
```

createQuery(query).getResultList();